# K NN Technique(sanket077047)

Tags: implementation, knn

i am doing project to classify stress using EEG signal. For this i am using kn N technique but i don't know how to implement this technique.Please help me to solve this query.I am using databse of 24 electrode of EEG and software to use is MATLAB.
  Also how to train network in matlab?

Comment: which tool you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

An example from http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/kmeans-clustering demonstrates *k*-means clustering in R, for a *k*-value of 3. The clustering vector shows you the classification assignment for each row of data:

```
> newiris <- iris
> newiris$Species <- NULL
> (kc <- kmeans(newiris, 3)) 
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 38, 50, 62

Cluster means:
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     6.850000    3.073684     5.742105    2.071053
2     5.006000    3.428000     1.462000    0.246000
3     5.901613    2.748387     4.393548    1.433871

Clustering vector:
  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [30] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3
 [59] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 [88] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 1
[117] 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1
[146] 1 3 1 1 3

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 23.87947 15.15100 39.82097

Available components:
[1] "cluster"  "centers"  "withinss" "size"
```

Basically, you need to figure out how to load your data into R, then run the `kmeans()` command on that data with the number of clusters you want to assign your data to.